# progress bar to keep user busy until the page loads from the server

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

On my main page the user selects the province and district field from the drop down and submits the page.On submit my page switches to  this page :action="barchart.php" where the user has to wait until the page completely loads.The problem is that the progress bar doesn't appear before the contents loads form the server.This is my database query.

```
<?php  
include("connect.php");
nclude("ajyx.php");
$pcode=$_POST['prv'];
$dcode=$_POST['des'];
$tcode=$_POST['teh'];
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$qry= "select hfc,hf_name  FROM health_facilities where p_code='". $pcode."'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$rec = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$vari[]= $row['hf_name'];
}
for($i=0;$i <sizeof($vari);$i++ ){
//$testing .= "'".$vari[$i]."',";
$testing .= "'".$vari[$i]."',";
}
$testing = rtrim($testing,',');
?>
```

How can I use $rec, which has contains the total no of records in db, variable to create a synchronous progress bar like gmail.I experimented with a couple of different scripts but in vain.Because the progress bar appears on the page after the contents load from the server.I need it to be visible on my page as the user presses the submit button.Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.Thank You.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you need a progress bar, it's taking too long ;)

Comment: Kolink:Necessity is the mother of invention.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow below step.

1. submits the page.On submit page switches to this page
   :action="barchart.php"
2. On barchart.php add code for showing progress bar.
3. Add ajax methode which will take requried bar chart output from
   mysql php using ajax.
4. Once you receive required output show this on page.
5. Close/hide the progress bar and show the container which contains bar chart output    -